# Getting error "not well-formed (invalid token)"

Tags: python, regex, xml, parsing, compare

I have an XML file with the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<metadata>
    <filter>
        <regex>ATL|LAX|DFW</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char></end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>DFW.+\.$</regex >
        <start_char>3</start_char>
        <end_char>-1</end_char>
        <action>remove</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\-</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <regex>\s</regex >
        <replacement></replacement>
        <action>substitute</action>
    </filter>
</metadata>
```

I am trying to read in the xml file into my python code and loop through all the filter tags and see if the action tag is 'remove'. If the action tag is 'remove', I want to remove the part of the mfn_pn that matches the text within the regex tag.

Next, I want it to see if the action tag is 'substitute'. If it is 'substitute', I want it to substitute the text within the regex tag with what's in the replacement tag.

However, I keep getting the error

> File "C:\Python\Python37-32\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 598, in parse
> self._root = parser._parse_whole(source)
> File "", line None
> xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 50, column 13".

Not sure what "not well-formed (invalid token)" is referring to.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

# filters.xml is the file that holds the things to be filtered
tree = ElementTree()
tree.parse("filters.xml")
```

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the error occurs in the first 4 lines of your script. As such, the rest of the script is not needed for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Having said that, interestingly  the example from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) yields the same error.

Finally, I managed to resolve the issue by following the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63779060/why-does-tree-elementtree-parsef-give-the-error-typeerror-parse-missin).

Comment: I looked at the example and tried doing:                                                                               
tree = ElementTree(), tree.parse("filters.xml"), root = tree.getroot(), try: (new line)  with open(root, 'filter') as x: (new line) root = ElementTree(), root.parse(x) (separated by new lines where the commas are), but I'm getting the error: "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 50, column 13".

Comment: When you said that there was an error in the first 4 lines of my script, did you mean the line containing "root = tree.getroot()" as well?

Comment: Your error occurs on line 4 (i.e. tree = ElementTree.parse("filters.xml")). As such, only the first 4 lines are needed to reproduce the error. As such, please update your question to only include the relevant code. Moreover, please update your question to include the new code that you tried and the result. It sounds like this error is resolved and that you're now getting another error.

Comment: I've updated the question with the new code and the error I'm getting. Thank you

Comment: I also removed code that is not needed to reproduce the error. This code snippet now runs without error on my machine given your xml file. Does it run correctly on yours?